# static block in java.lang.Object

Tags: java, object

When I execute `javap java.lang.Object` on the command line, it gives me the class structure which has all the available methods of `Object` class along with this block:

```
static {
    registerNatives();
}
```

What is the use of this static block in `java.lang.Object` class?

Comment: Show us what you are referring to.

Comment: @Tunaki - Yes I am not able to understand what does `registerNatives();` do and why is that called in a static block